# Raspberry pi portaudio not working with python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, microphone, portaudio, adafruit

I recently purchased the I2s microphone from adafruit and wired it to my raspberry Pi 3 Model A+. I want to use the module as the microphone but use the on board audio jack for the speaker.

Initially this worked with the terminal when recording with arecord and playing with aplay. When trying to use Python PyAudio it gave me many alsa errors and Jack errors such as:

`jack server is not running or cannot be started`

PyAudio:

```
import pyaudio
P = PyAudio()
```

I traced the error to be called in the initialization of PyAudio at the

```
pa.initialize()
```

The code did not break but didn't function how I wanted it to. I am hoping to use the speech recognition library but when I run it once again I get all these errors and then it just listens forever. When I used a timeout it would just give an error saying time out.

Would really appreciate any help, I have been stuck on this all week. I've looked across lots of simular issues and have not found a solution.